# Connect to MariaDB in Docker container from dbeaver

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I have Mariadb running in a container and can connect from terminal using the following command:
mysql -h 172.18.0.2 -u username -psecret
However, when attempting to set up in Dbeaver (a gui), I continue to get the error:

"Could not connect to 127.18.0.2:3308 : unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4 (socket was closed by server)
unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4 (socket was closed by server)
unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4 (socket was closed by server)"

The port is 3308, NOT 3306 - so I verified this is correct.

If I run:

docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' docker_mysql_1
I receive:
172.18.0.2

I have also attempted looking at Docker's IP addresses using docker ps and receive:

71a6e74bd790   mariadb:latest          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 hours ago   Up 33 minutes   3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3308->3308/tcp, :::3308->3308/tcp   docker_mysql_1

I tried the ip address in there as well in dbeaver with no success.

Currently, I am attempting using the following credentials in dbeaver:

host: 127.18.02 (I've tried localhost and other variations of localhost ip)
port: 3308 (I have tried 3306)
and of course, the username and password.
(I have tried username with "@localhost" and @ the ipaddress at end  - no success)

I have tried with and without using a database in the options.

I am using the MariaDB driver in dbeaver.

It seems I need to do more to map or expose the port.  I am new to Docker containers.  Thank you  in advance!

Comment: Is dbeaver running in a container too?

Comment: dbeaver is not running in the container.  It is a GUI program installed on the Ubuntu local machine.  I believe this to be part of the issue is I am not properly connecting it to the container.

Comment: If you are connecting directly to the container ip, you need to use port 3306 (port publishing only impacts connections to host addresses). Otherwise, you would need to connect to `localhost:3308` to access the published port. Generally, you don't want to use the container ip (because it changes every time you start a container).

Comment: Thank you!  I tried localhost on 3306 and it did change the error message.  The new error is (conn=8) Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
(conn=8) Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Edit - modified users table and restarted error is now: RSA public key is not available client side (option serverRsaPublicKeyFile not set)